# update mysql table row with unique row id

Tags: mysql

I want to update a table row within mysql that doesn't have row id's.

The table name is "unit_status"

```
unit     is_active   enabled
17625012    Active      0
```

I have 2 million of these but want to update this single row to change enabled to "1"

Comment: that will be complecated, how will you access the row when that have no unique id??????

Comment: Please post the full table structure.

Comment: Question could be read as I have 2 million rows where unit = 17625012 and is active = active and enabled = 0. Or it could be read as I have a table with 2 million rows but i want to change the one row where unit = 17625012 and is active = active and enabled = 0. Can you clarify please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
update unit_status
set enabled = 1
where unit = 17625012    
and is_active = 'Active'
and enabled = 0
limit 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
UPDATE unit_status SET enabled = 1 WHERE unit = 17625012 AND is_active = 'Active' AND enabled = 0
```

But you should always have a primary key or a unique key.

Comment: That would be an answer but we don't know if the 'unit' is unique.

Comment: Yes but if the unit is not unique then it is not possible to select exactly the desired row. If there are duplicates there is no way to access always the same.